# Change the automatic color of matplotlib to hex colors automatically python3

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I created a pie chart using matplotlib and I'd like to change the default colors to more softer colors, such as the hex RGB or RGBA string colors. I have the below script so far:

```
colors = ['#ff9999', '#66b3ff', '#99ff99', '#ffcc99']
explode = ((0.05,)*(len(annotation_df.index)))
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(annotation_df['count'], labels=annotation_df['annotation'], autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90, pctdistance=0.85, explode=explode,colors=colors)  #colors=colors,
# draw circle
centre_circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.70, fc='white')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)
# Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle
ax1.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The problem is I need the colors to be set automatically, and I don't want specifically write the colors, as written above in the script.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"? How should matplotlib know which colors you want to use?

Comment: In my script only 4 colors are mentioned, since the pie chart will be created dynamically each time with different set of values (not mentioned in here), it will need to use different number of colors. In my question I mean is there a different set of colors, more nice than the default one?

Comment: You mean you want to specify a set of 10 colors such that any pie with 1 to 10 wedges would use those?

Comment: 10 would be a good start, unless I will have more than 10 wedges, than it will use colors it already used...even more than 10 would be good. I'd like not to limit it if possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define a color cycler to contain the colors you want to use.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'] = plt.cycler('color', 
                                             ['#ff9999', '#66b3ff', '#99ff99', '#ffcc99'])

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie([1,2,3], labels=list("ABC"), autopct='%1.1f%%')

ax1.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

If you have less wedges than colors in the cycler only the those colors needed are used. If you have more wedges than colors in the cycler, they would be repeated. You can put as many colors as you like into the color cycler.